# Having trouble figuring out how to read mulitiple inputs in a input file in Java

Tags: java

I had a assignment to make a version of the Game of Life on Java but without the GUI and all the fancy stuff, just some simple coding. Basically, we have to design it in a way in which it reads a input file and outputs the result to another file. The format of the input file is as follows: First line is the dimensions of the grid. The next line is the number of needed generations. Then the grid containing 1s for the creatures and 0s for the spaces. The file terminates by 0 0.

```
5 5
1
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
5 5
2
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0
```

And the output to this should be:

```
Creature #1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

Creature #2
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I have most of my code finished but I have a one problem that I need some help/guidance with. I do not know how to make it move on to the next creature alone. Like it will solve the game for for the first grid but I do not know how to make it move on to the next grid and eventually terminate. Here is my code for it, please tell me anyway I can improve it and/or solve my issue.

Here is my code:

```
public class GameOfLife {

    int height;
    int width;
    int gen;
    int[][] grid;
    ArrayList<Integer> gridrow = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> gridcol = new ArrayList();

    public void readInput(String input) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(input));
        height = in.nextInt();
        width = in.nextInt();
        grid = new int[height][width];
        gen = in.nextInt();
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
                grid[row][column] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        in.nextLine();
    }

    public void nextGen() {
        int genNow = 0;
        while (genNow < gen) {
            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                    neighbours(row, col);
                }
            }
            genNow++;
        }
    }

    public void neighbours(int curRow, int curCol) {
        int count = 0;
        int strrow;
        int endrow;
        int strcol;
        int endcol;
        if (curRow - 1 < 0) {
            strrow = curRow;
        } else {
            strrow = curRow - 1;
        }

        if (curRow + 1 == height) {
            endrow = curRow;
        } else {
            endrow = curRow + 1;
        }

        if (curCol - 1 < 0) {
            strcol = curCol;
        } else {
            strcol = curCol - 1;
        }
        if (curCol + 1 == width) {
            endcol = curCol;
        } else {
            endcol = curCol + 1;
        }

        for (int row = strrow; row < endrow + 1; row++) {
            for (int col = strcol; col < endcol + 1; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count == 3) {
                gridrow.add(curRow);
                gridcol.add(curCol);
        } 
            }
        }
    }

    public void printOutput(String output) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(output));
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
                out.print(grid[row][col] + " ");
            }
            out.print("\n");
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

PS: keep in mind I am a beginner in Java and still do not really know a lot about it so any help/tips are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *Repat until EOF { Read W; Read H; Read N; Read H Lines Of W Chars; Convert to grid; Iterate game N times }* As a sketched flow.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Can you please expand on that? How do I iterate the game N times as a sketched flow?

Comment: Are there multiple grids in the same input file? After you read one grid what are you supposed to do with it? Note, you can assume that I am familiar with the rules for the game of life. I'm asking if you are supposed to run a certain number of generations for a given grid? Or is the next grid from the input somehow related to the grid before it?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `gridrow` and `gridcol`?

Comment: By calling `nextGen` *N* times? It's your code, you should know it :D

Comment: @Code-Apprentice there are multiple grids in the same input file as I showed at the very top yes, you are supposed to run however many gens is required for that same grid then you move on to the next grid or terminate the game, as applicable. The next grid has nothing to do with the one before it. The purpose of them is to store the coordinates for wherever I need to write a '1' then later extract them and put them into my 2D array grid.

Answer (score 1):

The critical part of this problem is

> The file terminates by 0 0.

You have not written anything to handle this situation.

If I were in your shoes, i would read the next line of the file get the dimensions of the grid first and see if it is the terminating condition; i.e., "0 0".

If not, I would feed the reader object (Scanner in your case) to the readInput method of the next GameOfLife  object.

The signature of the readInput method would be stg like;

```
public void readInput(Scanner scanner, int width, int height);
```

It may even be a static method that returns an instance of a GameOfLife class.

```
public class GameOfLife {

    int height;
    int width;
    int gen;
    int[][] grid;
    ArrayList<Integer> gridrow = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> gridcol = new ArrayList();

    public static GameOfLife readInput(Scanner scanner, int width, int height) {

        GameOfLife result = new GameOfLife();
        result.width = width;
        result.height = height;

        result.gen = scanner.readInt();
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
                result.grid[row][column] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        scanner.nextLine();
        return result;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the Scanner is created outside of the readInput method of the GameOfLife class (in the main function maybe?).

```
List<GameOfLife> list = new ArrayList<GameOfLife>();

Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(input));

while(true) {
        int width = in.readInt();
        int height = in.readInt();

        if(width != 0 && height != 0) {
            GameOfLife game = GameOfLife.readInput(in, width, height);
            list.add(game);
        }
        else
            break;
}

//then do anything you like with the list of GameOfLife objects
```